# Why is cURL sending this warning: '--' had unsupported trailing garbage

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, centos

I have a bash script with this section:

```
respuesta=$(curl -Ls -X GET http://api.wunderground.com/api/$key/conditions/lang:SP/q/$pais/$ciudad.json)
```

I did notice since I updated my centOS to the latest version, then I am getting this warning every time I use cURL in all my shell scripts.

```
Warning: /root/.curlrc:1: warning: '--' had unsupported trailing garbage
```

Comment: What's in the file /root/.curlrc?

Comment: Did you notice `$key`, `$pais`, `$ciudad` in your URL? If this called in a bash these will be considered as shell variables and replaced be their contents. (Non-existing variables are replaced with empty strings.) If this not your intention you have to apply some kind of quoting or escaping (e.g. single quotes which disable the expansion of nearly everything).

Comment: /root/.curlrc = -- --capath /etc/ssl/certs; These variables are setted with some data, this warning happen even if I use: curl "https://www.google.com"